# String manipulation in fish shell

Tags: fish

i wish to write a fish shell script to automatically initialize JAVA_HOME to current configured java-alternative.

In bash it would look like this (sorry for the ugly double dirname)

```
j=`update-alternatives --query javac | grep Value:`
JAVA_HOME=`dirname ${j#Value:}`
JAVA_HOME=`dirname $JAVA_HOME`
export JAVA_HOME
```

what about fish?

```
set j (update-alternatives --query javac | grep Value:)
set JAVA_HOME (dirname ${j#Value:}) <-- this won't work!!
set JAVA_HOME (dirname $JAVA_HOME)
set --export JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: I resigned string manipulation in favor of set --export JAVA_HOME (update-alternatives --query javac | grep Value: | sed -e "s/Value: //" | sed 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,' | sed 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash:

```
j=$(update-alternatives --query javac | sed -n '/Value: /s///p')
export JAVA_HOME=${j%/*/*}
```

Fish:

```
set j (update-alternatives --query javac | sed -n '/Value: /s///p')
set --export JAVA_HOME (dirname (dirname $j))
```

or

```
set --export JAVA_HOME (dirname (dirname (update-alternatives --query javac | sed -n '/Value: /s///p')))
```

Answer (score 26):

The fish shell now has a `string` builtin command for string manipulation. This was added in version 2.3.0 (May 2016).

E.g. in this case, we could use `string replace` to remove the `Value:` substring:

```
set j (update-alternatives --query javac | grep Value: | string replace 'Value: ' '')
set --export JAVA_HOME (dirname (dirname $j))
```

There's lots more that `string` can do. From the [string command documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string):

```
Synopsis

string length [(-q | --quiet)] [STRING...]
string sub [(-s | --start) START] [(-l | --length) LENGTH] [(-q | --quiet)]
           [STRING...]
string split [(-m | --max) MAX] [(-r | --right)] [(-q | --quiet)] SEP
             [STRING...]
string join [(-q | --quiet)] SEP [STRING...]
string trim [(-l | --left)] [(-r | --right)] [(-c | --chars CHARS)]
            [(-q | --quiet)] [STRING...]
string escape [(-n | --no-quoted)] [STRING...]
string match [(-a | --all)] [(-i | --ignore-case)] [(-r | --regex)]
             [(-n | --index)] [(-q | --quiet)] [(-v | --invert)] PATTERN [STRING...]
string replace [(-a | --all)] [(-i | --ignore-case)] [(-r | --regex)]
               [(-q | --quiet)] PATTERN REPLACEMENT [STRING...]
```

Comment: Wow, great! If I want to use the results of something like `string split " " "This is my teststring"` in a list variable, how would I do that?

Comment: @rassoh - By way of example: `set mylist (string split " " "This is my teststring")`

Comment: thanks, works great! Of course, to make it a list i had to do `set -l mylist (...)`

Comment: @rassoh - The `-l` flag changes the scope of the variable rather than its type. See the [set command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#set).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sed, u could make use of expr with a regexp, for example:

```
$ set a /path/to/some/folder/file.extension
```

the command:

```
$ expr "//$a" : '.*/\([^.]*\)\..*$'
file
```

extract the file basename without extension.

See `man expr`

Answer (score 0):

Fish shell:

```
~> set JAVA_HOME (readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::")
~> echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Output (example):

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Also u can add to `~/.config/fish/config.fish` this line:

```
set JAVA_HOME (readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::")
```

WBR